# Fortran WRITE loop to multiple files?

Tags: fortran

i want to create new file at each loop, i don't know how to do...

```
!file1, file2,....., file[n]

OPEN (1,FILE='file1.out',ACCESS='SEQUENTIAL',STATUS='UNKNOWN')
do ph=1,N6
do i=1,nx-1
    A(i)=mu*U(i-1)
end do
do j=0,nx
    U(j)=A(j)
end do 
    if (mod(ph,Ne)==0) then ! ?
    WRITE(1,200) nt,U(i)
    endif
    200 format(5E12.4)
end do
```

Or maybe, i can write with a newline or column ?
I'm a beginner in fortran.
Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit - the code example doesn't really help. Do you want to write the whole array `m` into multiple files, or do you want to write each element of `m` into a separate file? Try giving us us background on your problem so will be more able to suggest a decent answer.

Comment: Ok i add my code detailling. I want to write array U in a new file at each time. Because like this, i only have the last U on file1.out I want to see each U calcuted during the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing code should output more than just last write statement to the file ... it is a sequential file, which means that the output is added to the file in sequential order.   If you are only seeing one output, perhaps that is all that the IF statement is causing to be output?

If you still wish to output to multiple files, the easiest way to output to multiple files is to reuse the unit number and have the program create filenames.  You need to close the file / unit and reopen it.  This is much more easier than have multiple open statements and unit numbers, which would quickly become awkward as the number of files increased.  Here is a code fragment that assumes fewer than 100 files:

```
do i=1, N
  write (filename, '("myfile", I2.2, ".txt")' )  I 
  open (file=filename,unit=16,...)
  calculations...
  write (16,'(5E12.4)') nt,U(i)
  close (16)
end do
```

Comment: Thank you, its exactly what i wanted !

Comment: Ok for the sequential, i hadn't understand. I was thinking to an another way, but i don't kown if its possible, can i write in the same file but in different column U(i) ? But your solution is fine for me

Comment: @supertoto You can write in different columns in same file  by using `ADVANCE='NO'` in the write statement.